# How do I avoid reruning all the code when I restart Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook on Google Cloud Platform VM instance.

I finish work, stop the instance and restart vm and Jupyter Notebook the very next morning, I have to rerun all the codes from the top which is annoying because I have to load all the dataset and that takes good 30 minutes.

I googled around and found that these codes would work, but even though I have it on the top of my notebook still the same problem occurs.

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Is there any way to keep everything in the jupyter notebook so that I can just pick up and run it?

Comment: Possible workaround: store your datasets in pickle-files.

Comment: @AntonvBR I am pulling the dataset from GCP storage. From my bucket I mount dataset to a directory in vm instance. That's how I read the data. Would I be able to still store these data in pickle-files?

Comment: I just mean you can continue where you left off quicker by storing the variables of interest.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested,

I used python library called 'dill'

`dill.dump_session('notebook_env.db')
dill.load_session('notebook_env.db')`